# To cast or not to cast?

Tags: mysql

I am developing a system using MySQL queries written by another programmer, and am adapting his code.

I have three questions:

1.

One of the queries has this select statement:

```
SELECT
   [...]
   AVG(mytable.foo, 1) AS 'myaverage'`,
```

Is the 1 in `AVG(mytable.foo, 1) AS 'myaverage'` legitimate? I can find no documentation to support its usage?

2.

The result of this gives me average values to 2 decimal places, why?.

3.

I am using this to create a temp table. So:

```
(SELECT
    [...]
    AVG(`mytable`.`foo`, 1) AS `myaverage`,
FROM
    [...]
WHERE
    [...]
GROUP BY
    [...])
UNION
(SELECT
    [...]
FROM
    [...]
WHERE
    [...]
GROUP BY
    [...])
) AS `tmptable`
ORDER BY
    `tmptable`.`myaverage` DESC
```

When I sort the table on this column I get output which indicates that this average is being stored as a string, so the result is like:

9.3

11.1

In order to get around this what should I use?

Should I be using CAST or CONVERT, as DECIMAL (which I read is basically binary), BINARY itself, or UNSIGNED?

Or, is there a way to state that `myaverage` should be an integer when I name it in the AS statement?

Something like:

```
SELECT
    AVG(myaverage) AS `myaverage`, INT(10)
```

Thanks.

Comment: How does 9.3 < 11.1 show it's being stored as a string? Usually it is "11.1" < "9.3" but 9.3 < 11.1

Comment: It may be better to break this question into *different* SO posts. The first focusing on #1/#2 and the second focusing on #3. Welcome to SO.

Comment: for question 2: "Before MySQL 5.0.3, SUM() and AVG() return DOUBLE for all numeric arguments."

Comment: Thanks Sinan, no 2 makes sense now.

Comment: pst, sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I am sorting DESC.

Comment: @pst The sorting order is DESC, so 11.1 should come before 9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone who's interested, I must have deleted or changed my predecessors code so this `AVG` question was incorrect. The correct code was `ROUND(AVG(myaverage),1)`. Apologies to those who scrathed their heads over my stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

On your last question: can you post the exact MySQL query that you are using?

The result type of a column from a `UNION` is determined by everything you get back. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html .

So, even if your AVG() function returns a `DOUBLE`, the other part of the UNION may still return a string. In which case the column type of the result will be a string.

See the following example:

```
mysql> select a from (select 19 as a union select '120') c order by a;
+-----+
| a   |
+-----+
| 120 |
| 19  |
+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select a from (select 19 as a union select 120) c order by a;
+-----+
| a   |
+-----+
|  19 |
| 120 |
+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

on 1.
AVG() accepts exactly one argument, otherwise MySQL will raise an error:

```
mysql> SELECT AVG( id, 1 ) FROM anytable;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 1 )' at line 1
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Just because I'm curious - what should the second argument do?

Comment: I get no error from `AVG(`mytable`.`foo`, 1) `. I'm not sure what the second argument should do either, it's legacy code from before my time.

Comment: Might depend on version, which one do you use? I tried with 5.1.41